# Typescript absolute imports "These dependencies were not found" error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, import, tsconfig

Here's my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "app",
    "jsx": "react",
    "target": "esnext",
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "declaration": true,
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "lib": [
      "esnext", "dom"
    ],
  },
  
  "include": ["app"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "**/__tests__/*"]
}
```

And the folder structure looks something like this:

```
app
-> assets
   components
   contexts
   hooks
   ...
src
tests
...
tsconfig.json
```

where the `app` folder is the React UI and `src` is php code.

The problem happens when I'm trying to absolute import a file in `context/CurrentAccountContext`. Here are the imports:

```
import { useSessionAndLocalStorage } from 'hooks/useSessionAndLocalStorage';
import { useIsFirstRender } from 'hooks/useIsFirstRender';
import { Account } from 'models';
import { apiFetch } from '../util/apiFetch';
import { queryClient } from '../util/queryClient';
```

For some reason it's throwing this error:

```
Failed to compile with 2 errors          11:21:29 AM

These dependencies were not found:

* hooks/useIsFirstRender in ./app/context/CurrentAccountContext.tsx
* hooks/useSessionAndLocalStorage in ./app/context/CurrentAccountContext.tsx

To install them, you can run: npm install --save hooks/useIsFirstRender hooks/useSessionAndLocalStorage
```

What's interesting here is that I'm able to import from `models` but not from `hooks`. All `models` and `hooks` files are TS ones.
I'm slowly migrating this codebase from JS to TS so maybe there's something related to it, but I checked all imports and none of those have any JS references.
At this point I have no clue what this might be and tried several other `tsconfig.json` definitions. Will keep searching. If you have any idea what might be please share here =)

Thanks!

- Tried using `paths` property in `tsconfig.json`
- Tried `baseUrl` as `.`, `./`, `app` etc
- Tried using aliases